# antlr4 Similar token definition

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4, antlrworks

I've a problem with tokens definition.

here is my grammar.

```
r: PROPNAME ':' PROPVALUE
PROPNAME: [a-zA-Z]+
PROPVALUE: [a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

if I use

> name:christof123 it match

if I use

> name:christof it doesn't match

Arguing 'christof' is PROPNAME lexer when PROPVALUE waited since 'christof' matches both PROPVALUE & PROPNAME expressions.

But I don' want matching on

> name123:christof

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, the lexer will match christof with PROPNAME because that comes first in your definition that will match the longest. You can check the matches using `grun`.

```
antlr4 MyGrammer.g4
javac -g *.java
grun MyGrammer r -tokens
# enter your input string and press ctlr+d
```

Your grammar produces the below matches which gives the error.

```
name:christof
line 1:13 token recognition error at: '\n'
[@0,0:3='name',<2>,1:0]
[@1,4:4=':',<1>,1:4]
[@2,5:12='christof',<2>,1:5]
[@3,14:13='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
line 1:5 mismatched input 'christof' expecting PROPVALUE
```

So modifying your grammar to the below would solve.

```
r: name ':' value;

name: ALPHA;
value: ALPHA | ALPHANUM;

ALPHA: [a-zA-Z]+;
ALPHANUM: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

Which produces the following match with grun.

```
name:christof
line 1:13 token recognition error at: '\n'
[@0,0:3='name',<2>,1:0]
[@1,4:4=':',<1>,1:4]
[@2,5:12='christof',<2>,1:5]
[@3,14:13='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

Comment: Ok it seems work, the problem it's  I need an intermediate rules name & value that's it?

Comment: Welcome. You need to break the lexer rules into smaller units and combine it for such usecases.